# Appcelerator App Conversion iOS to Android.

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

One of our developer developed an app in appcelerator using alloy framework for iOS which works fine. Now we want to run the same app in Android, since the appcelerator is a cross platform tool, we wish to make the Android version of the App. I tried searching about it and explored the applcelerator ide for options but couldn't find it. Can some one please guide me into the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all have a look at this link : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Supporting_Multiple_Platforms_in_a_Single_Codebase this will guide you to update the application for multiple platforms.

Their are basically two different ways to port any application from **android** to **iOS** or vise-versa, but before that just let me clear one more thing to you about `tiapp.xml`.

In the `tiapp.xml` of your project you need to updated the **Development Target** by checking for which platform you are developing the application for (iPhone, iPad, android, Mobile Web).[image: Have a look at the image]

**Option 1 :**

Cross Platform is build to make code re-usable (i.e. re-use  same code for all the platforms), but we have exceptions with many things. Their are lot of components that work fine in iOS but when you use them in android then you will face errors. So in that case you just need to apply conditions for android and iOS like below :

```
if(OS_ANDROID)
    // do something
else if(OS_IOS)
    // do something
```

What you need to do is that you need run the application in android simulator and test the application for these changes and then apply the changes accordingly.

Basically a developer has to target the UI for both the platforms, as their will not be any logical differences between the two. Also their will be UI changes between the same components, like for example a picker in iOS will not look the same as it will when you look it in an android application.

**Option 2 :**

Now in the project you have assets folder with the platform that you have selected in the `tiapp.xml` (i.e. iPhone, android etc).

You can create similar structure in the **style** and **view** folder, create two folders **iOS** and **android** in both the directory (i.e. style and view).

First, move `.tss` of style folder (except app.tss and index.tss) in the iOS folder, then copy the files in the android folder also.

Repeat the similar process with the View folder also.

Now you have two different structures (i.e. view and styles) according to their platform. Now you can run the application in android simulators and resolve the error that you face.

Hope this small information helps the cause, you can also have look at the documentation of all the components from below link :

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Indeed a detailed answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Jeet : Your welcome and I have update the answer also with one more link.